# What is the best possible user multi-currency wallet database design?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, mongoose-schema, wallet

I'm using mongodb/mongoose, my app new requirements is to have multiple currencies, and each user can have a different balance for each currency.
ex: A user can have 30 USD, 100 EUR, 200 EGP.
No exchange from one currency to another, just a bunch of currencies.
At the moment we don't have any currencies, just a field called "balance" which contains user's balance.
My solution is to create a table for currencies, each with an _id and a name.
but when it comes to user balance I can't determine what is the best solution to make increasing and decreasing user balance easy, the only solution that crosses my mind is making balance field an array of object

```
balance: [{ currency: "CurrenyId", amount: 50 }, { currency: "CurrenyId", amount: 100 }]
```

But the problem with this approach is updating balance would be troublesome, Would you suggest a better solution ?
thanks